# Do inline expressions obstruct readability of code?

Tags: clean-code, variables, code-complete

Currently, I'm reading "Code Complete" by Steve McConnell, 24.3 chapter "Specific Refactorings". I've become kind of confused with 4th paragraph, that looks like:

> ***Move an expression inline*** Replace an intermediate variable that was
> assigned the result of an expression with the expression itself.

Does that inline expression decrease readability of code compared to a well-named (even if it intermediate) variable? When will it be recommended to use inline expressions and when intermediate variables?

Comment: This is a valid question.  Some practices suggested in older books may be outdated; when it’s counterintuitive, it’s therefore wise to question them :-)

Comment: The problem with such rules stated abstractly, is that there are equally cases where moving an inline expression to an intermediate variable will be clearer.

Comment: Notice that what you have in that book is a *catalogue* of refactorings - these aren't recommendations, it's simply a list of things that you can do to shuffle code around, often as an intermediate step before you get to some goal (a way to "make the change easy, then make the easy change", to paraphrase Kent Beck). Yes, there's a refactoring named "**Move an expression inline** [...]" listed in there, but there's also the exact opposite: "**Introduce an intermediate variable** Assign an expression to an intermediate variable whose name summarizes the purpose of the expression."

Comment: Good names tend to increase readability, and inlining an expression removes a name. Was the name bringing anything to readability? If so, you just obstructed readability.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović So if you try to apply all the rules, you end up in an infinite loop :) Sounds like a good XKCD.

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA Also verbiage obstructs readability (all else being equal). Was the name used in two or more places? If so, you just obstructed readability.

Comment: @Barmar: sure if you treat them as rules, but my point was precisely that these *aren't* rules, it's just a list. E.g., if you want to extract a piece of code into a separate function, you might want to first refactor an inline expression into a variable, move that variable in front of the code you want to extract, then use your refactoring tool to extract the function. The tool can then figure out that you've referenced a variable external to the selection, and create a parameter for it. Once that code is replaced with a function call, you, might decide to get rid of the interm. variable. 1/3

Comment: So, not design rules, but a list of common refactorings. E.g., suppose you have some ad hoc code that checks if a point is in a rectangle + some padding around it, and then does something if the condition passes, and something else if it doesn't. You want to extract that code into a function so you can call it elsewhere, with a different rectangle. The code has in it: `if (clientRectangle.Inflate(padding).contains(point))`. 2/3

Comment: You introduce a local variable `var testRectangle = clientRectangle.Inflate(padding);`, and move that a few lines up. You then make the selection, and tell your refactoring tool to extract a function - it creates a one with the 'testRectangle' parameter: `handlePoint(point, testRectangle)`. You then might decide to do `handlePoint(point, clientRectangle.Inflate(padding))`, and elswhere you might call it like this `handlePoint(point, config.boundingRectangle)`. If I'm not mistaken, the book discusses code smells elsewhere. 3/3

Comment: @FilipMilovanović That was the joke, "if you treat them as rules".

Comment: @Barmar - Hey, don't get me wrong, I'm a great fan of XKCD :) I just thought it might be a good idea to sort of expand on my previous comment for the benefit of anyone who might stumble upon this question, and used your remark as a jumping off point.

Comment: Using local variables can be useful in making lines shorter and group in logical units. which can help readability.  Unfortunately it introduces _naming_ as these local variables needs a very good name which can be really hard, and even decrease readability if chosen poorly.     This is where peer review can be helpful.

Comment: Also there is the special case of return values.  Many debuggers cannot easily display the value being returned, and/or having breakpoints allowing you to change it.  By capturing it in a local variable you can do that.

Comment: Now imagine a statement “return f() + g() + h();” and you suspect g() returns the wrong result. Lots of work for your debugger.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Personally I prefer having temporary variables with explicit names (but don't abuse them either).

For me:

```cpp
void foo()
{
    int const number_of_elements = (function_1() + function_2()) / function_3(); // Or more complex expression

    write(number_of_elements);
}
```

is clearer than:

```cpp
void foo()
{
    write((function_1() + function_2()) / function_3());
}
```

But if you use temporary variables for something like:

```cpp
void foo()
{
    int const number_of_elements = get_number_of_elements();

    write(number_of_elements);
}
```

This is less readable than:

```cpp
void foo()
{
    write(get_number_of_elements());
}
```

I am not the author so I can't know what he was thinking when writing this line but it is a possibility.

The book being quite old (18 years for the second edition) there might also be historical reasons for that...

Comment: Nowadays, every decent compiler optimizes unneeded local variables away.  This was not necessarily the case when the book was written (for quite a while people even added `register` to local variables to hint the compiler about optimizations)

Comment: @ f222 & @Christophe - the book simply lists various refactorings that one can do on the path towards some final state of the code, they are not intended as recommendations (in fact, a couple of lines later), it lists the exact opposite refactoring ("introduce local/intermediate variable").

Comment: @FilipMilovanović indeed a couple of paragraphs  below he also proposes "Introduce an intermediate variable. Assign an expression to an intermediate variable whose name summarizes the purpose of the expression.” which leaves it to the write to chose what’s lost suitable

Comment: Note that in languages that have assignment expressions, you can simultaneously have named temporary variables *and* inline expressions, e.g. `write(number_of_elements = (function_1() + function_2()) / function_3());`.  But that's probably even less clear.

Comment: Example #1 is not much clearer than #2 if you gave it a decent name, like `void writeNumberOfElements() { write( (function_1() + function_2()) / function_3()); }`. However, would still prefer example #4 most of the time.

Comment: Functions should preferably either describe a single low level calculation or process, or a higher level process in terms of composition of other functions or results. Examples #1, #2, and #3 are doing both under the same function definition, which is why they're not as good as #4.

Comment: The most important job of code is to be understood by developers later (including yourself). A blazing-fast program that is impossible to understand (and thus fix or modify) is worth a lot less than an equivalent program that runs marginally slower but is crystal-clear in its purpose and methods (in _almost_ all circumstances; there are exceptions).

Comment: @Christophe Even 18 years ago, the `register` keyword was ignored by all major C/C++ compilers because they did a better job than a human.  You'd have to go back to the 80's to find to a time where it was meaningful.

Comment: FWIW I don't think the version with the temporary variable is any more readable than the code without it would have been if a *comment* — what a concept! — was added explaining what was being calculated. It also makes the performance discussion moot.

Comment: With function names so poor, no wonder the intermediate variable version is clearer.

Comment: At least when generating code for ARM-based targets, gcc's non-buggy mode can generate much better code if the `register` keyword is used than if it isn't.

Comment: Fundamentally, it comes down to making the code name things as much as possible.  Whether it's an inline variable or a function name makes no difference to me.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - "register" makes it illegal to take the address of the variable if I remember right, so it cannot be completely ignored.

Answer (score 26):

I think there are two key factors here:

- How complex is the expression?
- How meaningful is the intermediate variable?

Take an example where we have three elements to get a final price:

```
total = price + tax - discount;
```

An intermediate variable used only once is probably a bad idea:

```
taxed_price = price + tax;
total = taxed_price - discount;
```

But if the "taxed_price" variable is actually used repeatedly in the function, then naming *and reusing* it might make sense.

Meanwhile, if the individual elements are all themselves expressions, the full expression becomes unwieldy inline:

```
total = product.get_price() + calculate_tax(jurisdiction, product) - session.get_active_discount();
```

In this case, there are few enough operators that we can put a line break next to each one, which helps, but it's still hard to see at a glance what the overall calculation is doing

```
total = product.get_price() 
    + calculate_tax(jurisdiction, product)
    - session.get_active_discount();
```

In this case, introducing single-use variables makes it easier to read:

```
price = product.get_price();
tax = calculate_tax(jurisdiction, product);
discount = session.get_active_discount();
total = price + tax - discount;
```

But the variables are chosen to be meaningful, not just arbitrary break points - this doesn't really help, if `taxed_price` is only used once:

```
taxed_price = product.get_price() - calculate_tax(jurisdiction, product);
discount = session.get_active_discount();
total = taxed_price - discount;
```

And this is almost certainly nonsensical (it's hard to even *name* the variable, which is always a bad smell):

```
price = product.get_price();
tax_minus_discount = calculate_tax(jurisdiction, product) - session.get_active_discount();
total = price + tax_minus_discount;
```

Comment: Your "unwieldy line" example becomes perfectly ok if you just break it out into three lines, such as `total = product.get_price()` and `+ calculate_tax(jurisdiction, product)` and `- session.get_active_discount();`. No need to introduce any variables for that.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I've added an example with line breaks, and some commentary on why I think the intermediate variables are still an improvement. The more complex the sub-expressions, the more obvious that would be.

Answer (score 16):

“Refactoring” means changing what the code looks like, without changing what it does. A book about refactoring will tell you about changes you can make and how to make them without affecting what your code does.

You will often find a description how to change A to B, followed by a description how to change B to A - and your job is to find out which is actually an improvement. Sometimes A is better, sometimes B. The book tells you how to make the change, not what’s better.

Answer (score 7):

Local immutable variables (`const` in `C++`, `final` in`Java`, etc.) can add useful context-dependent information for the reader of the code and are useful when debugging interactively (stepping statement-by-statement). They are a trivial for the optimizer to get rid of, so thus can generally  be considered a useful “zero cost abstraction”.

Otherwise, when the context is clear and debugger ergonomics is not of a concern, then they are just a syntactic noise (especially if syntactically mutable), and more of a disturbance.

So overall — a matter of taste, I’d say.

Comment: "They are [...] trivial for the optimizer to get rid of" Beware semantic differences. In C++ a temporary with a nontrivial destructor is destroyed at the end of the _statement_, whereas a local variable is destructed _at the end of its scope_. I have fixed bugs caused by someone callously pulling out temporaries into local variables before.

Comment: C++ compilers don't really need `const` to optimize. But it's quite useful for humans reading the code.

Comment: @TLW const affects available signatures selection scope, so it will compile a bit faster too

Comment: @MSalters - there _are_ a fair number of cases where `const` locals affect potential optimizations. For instance if you pass a const pointer or reference to said local to a function it might be mutated under you unless the local itself is `const`. (C++'s "`const` is actually an attribute of the storage not the pointer/reference" comes into play here.)

Comment: For an example of this sort of missed optimization: https://godbolt.org/z/WYbnjhhx8 . Note that `foo_norm` and `foo_const` are identical except for the latter having a `const` in the local variable definition (and the function name of course), and yet the output is very different.

Comment: ("But I'd never write that code", you say. _You_ might not, but C++ relies heavily on inlined and optimized-out code. Some random `static inline` function somewhere in a header, when inlined a couple of levels, might very well have that sort of code.)

Comment: " it might be mutated under you" - correction: "mutated _out from_ under you". And it's been too long so I can't edit the comment.

Comment: Another point to consider in C++ is move semantics. A temporary is automatically moved from when appropriate, but but with named intermediate explicit std::move is needed and the object will remain in scope in invalid state.

Comment: @ojs - not in an invalid state, rather in a valid, but an unspecified state (17.6.5.15).

Comment: @bobah please have a medal for setting me straight

Comment: @ojs - hmm, how would I drink a medal?

Comment: I languages would support a concept of local immutable temporary variables whose names could be reused, subject to the constraint that if a name would get redefined on any path between a definition and a read, it must be redefined on every such path.

Comment: The java compiler has become so smart that it can detect that a variable _could_ be declared final and treat it accordingly.  This is very helpful with Java8+ language constructs.

Answer (score 5):

No language was specified, so I'll give a few examples.

- In languages with const correctness (e.g., C or C++) I make more intermediate variables

  - Always make intermediate variables `final` or `const` using any/all tools you have
  - in C++, use references (`const Type&`) if appropriate (be careful with ownership)
  - in C, use pointers (`const Type* const` ) if appropriate (maybe don't make something a pointer that wasn't already one)
- Languages without that, like C# or Python, I think there's diminishing returns to having a lot of intermediate variables

### Consider creating an inline variable if:

#### You can add context to the return value of a generic function

- What image are we reading and why is it important?

```cs
// C#
byte[] trainingImage = ReadImage("car1.png");
byte[] validationImage = ReadImage("car2.png");
```

#### You want to cache the result of a slow or unreliable operation

- If you really only need to query something once, do it only once.
- Don't sprinkle extra slow or unreliable operations throughout your code, then you have to spread that dependency and its error handling throughout your code too.
- Also remember that remote resources could "change" their answer the next time you contact them, which could lead to unexpected results.

```cs
// C#
Response telescopeResponse = RequestHubbleTelescopeData();
// do something with response
```

#### If it helps you provide better error messages

Inline expressions can make you tempted to lump all of them into the same recovery strategy even when that might not be a good fit.

Instead of one line that opens a file and parses the data,

- Open the file in one of the lines, and be prepared to handle errors/exceptions about file I/O, file not found, etc.
- In a separate line, process the data, and be prepared to handle exceptions about data in the wrong format, missing information, etc.

#### To document the code (better than comments)

From my answer to [Windows API dialogs without using resource files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48009861):

Here hopefully it's clear why I am adding 1 to the length.

```cpp
// C
int textLength_WithNUL = GetWindowTextLength(txtEditHandle) + 1;
```

From my answer to [Get rid of the white space around matlab figure's pdf output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44738063)

Here I unpack width/height from OldAxisPosition, so hopefully people don't need to look up what each index is.

```matlab
% matlab

%% Get old axis position and inset offsets 
%Note that the axes and title are contained in the inset
OldAxisPosition = get(AxisHandle,   'Position');
OldAxisInset    = get(AxisHandle,   'TightInset');

OldAxisWidth    = OldAxisPosition(3);
OldAxisHeight   = OldAxisPosition(4);

OldAxisInsetLeft    = OldAxisInset(1);
OldAxisInsetBottom  = OldAxisInset(2);
OldAxisInsetRight   = OldAxisInset(3);
OldAxisInsetTop     = OldAxisInset(4);
```

#### To point out intermediate variables that somebody might want to monitor for debugging

I may want to know where the player was prior to the collision, so I can see whether `SimulateCollision` is working properly.

```cs
// C#
Point3D oldPosition = player.Position;
Point3D newPosition = SimulateCollision(player, otherObject);
player.Position = newPosition;
```

#### Consider not creating an inline variable if:

- There isn't a descriptive name for the variable, or the name is very long.

  - Long names can be more annoying in languages without good linting / static type systems.
- The name of the variable is more or less just repeating the function name and doesn't provide any other value-add

```cs
// C#
string productPrice = GetProductPrice();
```

- The class property/field/etc. that you're reading from is already contextually appropriate and clear, and the property isn't slow or unreliable

```cs
// C#
string customerAddress = customer.Address;
```

- You are doing math but the intermediate calculation doesn't make any sense on its own

This is a bit of a judgment call because sometimes I do this when dividing.

```cpp
// C++
const float squareRootOfXPlus5 = sqrt(x + 5.0);
```

- Making an intermediate variable involves an extremely expensive copy operation and there's no practical way to avoid it
- In duck typed languages (e.g., Python), it may not be worth storing the value of a `dict` instead of just accessing it by key

```py
# python
customer_name = customer['name']
```

Comment: Definitely "To point out intermediate variables that somebody might want to monitor for debugging"  The main time I will change something like this in someone else's code is if I need to split out the return values so I can see which one has a problem.

Comment: @Dragonel Depends on your language. In Java, we can easily evaluate expressions in the debugger while paused, so no need to prepare temporary variables ahead of time (and then inevitably realize you don't have quite the right one you need and have to go change it, etc.). This has even improved over the past few years with better support for debugging fluent interfaces.

Comment: @user3067860 That doesn't solve the problem, at all. If you see in your variable that it has the wrong value, but cannot inspect the intermediate values in the debugger, then what? Re-type parts of the expression until you find the sub-expression where a value si wrong? thats cumbersome. Its much esier to read the code and debug it when there are already *meaningful* intermediate values present as variables.

Comment: @Polygnome also, in some cases, even if you did re-type parts of the expression, anything that had side effects would happen over again (not saying that's necessarily a sign of good API design, but I've seen it).

Comment: @Polygnome Select, right click, "evaluate expression".

Answer (score 1):

```
Customer customer = Customer.builder()
  .name("John Doe")
  .age(15)
  .address(Address.builder()
    .number(15)
    .street("Maple street")
    .build()
  )
  .build();
```

vs.

```
Address address = Address.builder()
  .number(15)
  .street("Maple street")
  .build();

Customer customer = Customer.builder()
  .name("John Doe")
  .age(15)
  .address(address)
  .build();
```

Imagine going overboard with the first case (deep builders) - I've seen that, what a mess.

Just treat each case separately, don't inline everything because the book said you can.